# Why does the helium hydride ion have such a large dipole moment?

Tags: ions, dipole

According to Wikipedia, the helium hydride ion $\ce {HeH+}$ has a dipole moment of 2.26 or 2.84. What contributes to this large dipole moment in this molecular ion?

Comment: "2.26 or 2.84" That's quite a large variation o.O Did you pick the two values from two different sources?

Comment: @GaurangTandon For a particle so rare and obscure, that's OK.

Comment: Think of it as a heteronuclear diatomic then a dipole is expected. Either the bond length is large or charge shift great or both. You will have to look into details of bonding to understand further.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_hydride_ion The bond is 0.77A long (H2 0.74A),

Comment: Just a note, the source for those dipole values isn't the best. It seems it was from a self published article using a minimal basis set in a home made program. The reason for the range is that when they compared it to GAMESS calculations, the value varied between those two when using two different STO-3G basis sets. A higher level of theory and better basis set could lead to much different results.

Comment: @Tyberius I see. In that case, are you aware of any better sources of this calculated dipole moment data? So you are saying that the dipole moment may not be as large as Wikipedia claims?

Comment: @TanYongBoon I would surmise it is pretty large with on the positive charge localizing on the hydrogen side. I just thought it was worth knowing that I wouldn't put much faith in those particular values. For such a small molecule, a much more accurate calculation could be done on a normal computer in a matter of minutes.

Comment: @Tyberius I actually just did a calculation using the functional CCST with 6-311G ++ (3df,3dp) basis set and obtained a value of 4 debyes!

Comment: @TanYongBoon I guess it isn't too surprising that's it even higher, considering it's ionic

Answer (score 3):

The dipole moment of an array of charges is defined as
$$
\vec{\mu}=\sum_i \vec{r}_iq_i
$$
where $\vec{r}_i$ is the position of charge $q_i$ in the molecule with respect to the center of mass. In a neutral molecule the sum of the charges is zero and therefore the terms in the sum partially cancel. For ions this is of course not the case and the dipole moment is much larger than for the corresponding neutral molecule (provided that the ion is not completely symmetric such as H$_2^+$).